# Are unit quaternions and quaternion group different?

Tags: representation-theory, quaternions

I am studying real representation from the book Representation theory by Fulton and Harris. Here I find an example which demonstrates the fact that if the character of a representation is real then the underlying representation need not be real. For instance the author take $G$ to be a finite non-abelian subgroup of $SU(2).$ To find this he identified $SU(2)$ with the unit quaternions. Now my question $:$ What are unit quaternions? What is difference of it with quaternion group? Any help will be warmly appreciated.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Unit quaternions are the multiplicative group of the quaternions of norm $1$, where by norm we mean $$\lVert q\rVert=\sqrt{q_1^2+q_i^2+q_j^2+q_k^2}=\sqrt{q^*q}=\sqrt{qq^*}$$

and $(a+bi+cj+dk)^*=a-bi-cj-dk$ is the conjugate quaternion. The conjugate quaternion works in similar fashion to the complex conjugate, with the main thing to care about being that $(pq)^*=q^*p^*$. So, for instance, in the complex representation of the quaternion we have $(z_1+z_jj)^*=z_1^*-jz_j^*=z_1^*-z_jj$.

The quaternion group $Q_8$ usually indicates its finite subgroup $\{1,-1,i,-i,j,-j,k,-k\}$.

Comment: Side note: the group structure of the nonzero quaternions is completely determined by $Q_8$ plus $\mathbb{R}$-bilinearity of multiplication. To make this precise, let $A$ be the group algebra $\mathbb{R}[Q_8]$, modulo the ideal generated by $1 - (-1)$ (i.e. we make the group elements $1, -1 \in Q_8$ additive inverses in $A$). Then $A$ is isomorphic to quaternions! $Q_8$ is the smallest subgroup of the nonzero quaternions which "generates" the quaternions in this way.